# Why is Django considering these 2 same querysets as different?

Tags: python, django

I have 2 Django models - DJs and Songs. I'm trying to get sets of all the songs with the same name for a particular DJ.

This is how I'm doing that

```
for dj in DJ.objects.all():
    song_group_list = []
    dj_song_list = Song.objects.filter(artist=dj)
    for song in dj_song_list:
        song_group = dj_song_list.filter(name=song.name).order_by('song_id')
        if len(song_group) > 1:
            if song_group not in song_group_list:
                song_group_list.append(song_group)
    for group in song_group_list:
        print group
```

This outputs 2 duplicate sets with the same queryset results.

```
[<Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>]
[<Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>, <Song: Wake Up>]
```

Why is the `not in` not able to distinguish between these 2 querysets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at `Queryset`'s [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L49) I couldn't find any `__eq__` method, so that is why when you're comparing two different instances of `Queryset` you're not finding any match.

```
>>> class A(object):
    pass

>>> A() == A()
False
>>> A() in [A()]
False
```

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__):

> If no `__cmp__()`, `__eq__()` or `__ne__()` operation is defined, class
>   instances are compared by object identity (“address”).